# onChange react-hook-form datepicker value is not getting

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form, react-datepicker

I am trying to use `react-datepicker` with `react-hook-form`. On submit form I am able to get datepicker value. But I am unable to get datepicker value on `onChange` form.

The versions which I am using are:

```
"react-hook-form": "^7.43.1"
"react-datepicker": "^4.10.0"
```

I have configured `react-datepicker` with `react-hook-form` like this:

App.tsx

```
import "./styles.css";
import Form from "./components/Form";
import FormInput from "./components/FormInput";
import FormDate from "./components/FormDate";

interface ConnectedFormValues {
  name: string;
  validFrom: Date | null;
}

export default function App() {
  const defaultValues: ConnectedFormValues = {
    name: "defaultName",
    validFrom: null
  };

  const onSubmit = (data: ConnectedFormValues) => {
    console.log(data);
  };

  const onChange = (data: ConnectedFormValues) => {
    console.log(data); //Here datepicker value should log into the console like input field.
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Form
        onSubmit={onSubmit}
        onChange={onChange}
        defaultValues={defaultValues}
      >
        {({ formState }) => {
          return (
            <div>
              <FormInput
                name="name"
                rules={{
                  required: { value: true, message: "This input is required" }
                }}
              />
              <FormDate
                name="validFrom"
                rules={{
                  required: {
                    value: true,
                    message: "This input is required"
                  }
                }}
              />

              <button type="submit" disabled={!formState.isDirty}>
                Submit
              </button>
            </div>
          );
        }}
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

FormDate.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";
import { Controller, RegisterOptions, useFormContext } from "react-hook-form";

export interface FormDateProps {
  name: string;
  defaultValue?: Date;
  rules?: Omit<
    RegisterOptions,
    "valueAsNumber" | "valueAsDate" | "setValueAs" | "disabled"
  >;
}

export const ControlledFormDate = ({ name, rules, ...rest }: FormDateProps) => {
  const { control } = useFormContext();

  return (
    <Controller
      control={control}
      name={name}
      rules={rules}
      render={({ field: { onChange, onBlur, value, ref } }) => (
        <ReactDatePicker
          {...rest}
          onChange={onChange}
          onBlur={onBlur}
          selected={value}
          ref={ref}
        />
      )}
    />
  );
};

export default ControlledFormDate;
```

Here is my [sandbox code](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-leaf-1q5fbb?file=/src/components/FormDate.tsx)